# C# Unit testing Complex multi threaded database reads

Tags: c#, database, multithreading, unit-testing, moq

I have a scenario where the most efficient approach to reading a lot of data and processing it is to  have a thread looking at a table for each hour of the day to produce a list of files in that hour. For each of the rows returned the thread, loads the file data (Oracle BLOB) into memory, processes it, tidies up and moves onto the next file.

So if we get a file at 12:00 and 14:00 in a day;

1. we get threads looking for rows between 00:00 and 12:00 that return no data and finish quickly
2. We get the 12:00 thread getting a single row, reading the blob and processing it, take a bit more time
3. Thread looking at 13:00 getting no rows
4. 14:00 same as 12:00
5. 15:00 - 23:00 same as item one.

So how do I stop my mock objects on IDbCommand mocks returning the wrong IDataReader mocks?

I am using Moq and the moq extension for IDataReader. In the test I have setup

```
        Mock<IDBConnectionFactory> mainDbFactory = new Mock<IDBConnectionFactory>();
        Mock<IDBConnectionFactory> repoDbFactory = new Mock<IDBConnectionFactory>();
        Mock<IRecoveryControlCallback> callbacks = new Mock<IRecoveryControlCallback>();
        Mock<IDbConnection> dbMainConnection = new Mock<IDbConnection>();
        Mock<IDbCommand> dbMainCommand = new Mock<IDbCommand>();
        Mock<IDataReader> dbNoFileRowReader = new Mock<IDataReader>();
        Mock<IDataReader> dbFileRowReader = new Mock<IDataReader>();
        Mock<IDataReader> dbLoadFile1Reader = new Mock<IDataReader>();
        Mock<IDataReader> dbLoadFile2Reader = new Mock<IDataReader>();

        // Handle call backs!
        callbacks.Setup(c => c.OnRecoveryStartedEvent(It.IsAny<string>())).Callback(new Action<string>(LogCallBack));

        // setup main mocks
        mainDbFactory.Setup(c => c.CreateRead()).Returns(dbMainConnection.Object);
        dbMainConnection.Setup(c => c.CreateCommand()).Returns(dbMainCommand.Object);
        dbMainCommand.SetupSequence(c => c.ExecuteScalar())
                     .Returns(mainStartDate)
                     .Returns(mainEndDate);

        dbNoFileRowReader.SetupDataReader(new List<FileNameRow>());
        dbFileRowReader.SetupDataReader(new List<FileNameRow>()
                     {
                         new FileNameRow() { fil_idr = 1, fil_nme = "file_one.xml"},
                         new FileNameRow() { fil_idr = 2, fil_nme = "file_two.xml"},
                     });

        dbLoadFile1Reader.SetupDataReader(new List<FileLoadRecord>()
                     {
                         new FileLoadRecord() { fil_con_dtl = LoadFile("file_one.xml") }
                     });

        dbLoadFile2Reader.SetupDataReader(new List<FileLoadRecord>()
                     {
                         new FileLoadRecord() { fil_con_dtl = LoadFile("file_two.xml") }
                     });

        dbMainCommand.SetupSequence(c => c.ExecuteReader())
                     .Returns(dbNoFileRowReader.Object)
                     .Returns(dbNoFileRowReader.Object)
                     .Returns(dbNoFileRowReader.Object)
                     .Returns(dbNoFileRowReader.Object)
                     .Returns(dbNoFileRowReader.Object)
                     .Returns(dbNoFileRowReader.Object)
                     .Returns(dbNoFileRowReader.Object)
                     .Returns(dbNoFileRowReader.Object)
                     .Returns(dbNoFileRowReader.Object)
                     .Returns(dbNoFileRowReader.Object)
                     .Returns(dbNoFileRowReader.Object)
                     .Returns(dbNoFileRowReader.Object)
                     .Returns(dbFileRowReader.Object)
                     .Returns(dbLoadFile1Reader.Object)
                     .Returns(dbFileRowReader.Object)
                     .Returns(dbLoadFile2Reader.Object)
                     .Returns(dbNoFileRowReader.Object)
                     .Returns(dbNoFileRowReader.Object)
                     .Returns(dbNoFileRowReader.Object)
                     .Returns(dbNoFileRowReader.Object)
                     .Returns(dbNoFileRowReader.Object)
                     .Returns(dbNoFileRowReader.Object)
                     .Returns(dbNoFileRowReader.Object)
                     .Returns(dbNoFileRowReader.Object)
                     .Returns(dbNoFileRowReader.Object)
                     .Returns(dbNoFileRowReader.Object)
                     .Returns(dbNoFileRowReader.Object)
```

Now, what I am seeing is that the threads with no things to do are moving so fast they take the data meant for the 'LoadFile' method and fail the test. If I move the LoadData result sets to the end the method gets empty result sets and fails as well.